# How to change color and add grid lines on python surface plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new here, please be gentle.
I am doing a project which requires me to draw the figure of octupole. I used python surface plot and got a result like this:

[image: the figure I got]

However, my professor wants something like this:

[image: the figure I want]

Please ignore the 226Ra in the figure. I want to change the color of my plot to red, and add the grid lines like that. Is there any way I can do it?
I would be very appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np;
from matplotlib import cm, colors;
import cmath;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D;
import scipy.special as sp;




l = 3    # degree
m = 0    # order
PHI, THETA = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:300j, 0:np.pi:150j]
R = sp.sph_harm(m, l, PHI, THETA).real

s = 1
X = (s*R*0.28+1) * np.sin(THETA) * np.cos(PHI)
Y = (s*R*0.28+1) * np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
Z = (s*R*0.29+1) * np.cos(THETA)

norm = colors.Normalize()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'), figsize=(14,10))
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=cm.jet(norm(R)))
m.set_array(R)
fig.colorbar(m, shrink=0.8);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace your `plot_surface` line with the following and comment out `fig.colorbar(m, shrink=0.8);`. You can use any other color as per your wish from [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html) page.

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10, color='orangered', edgecolors='k', lw=0.6)
```

**Output**

[image]